# Docker log mount folder is not synced

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

As the title, springboot project, if you enter the inside of the container, you can see that the log is generated normally, and the folder permissions of the host have been changed to 777, but the file folder of the log folder cannot be synchronized, and the folder of the host machine is still empty. Seeking answer =. =

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
LABEL maintainer="XXX"
WORKDIR /opt/XXX
ADD target/dist/XXX/ /opt/XXX/
ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime && echo ${TZ} > /etc/timezone 
EXPOSE 9999
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Denv=PRO","-jar","/opt/XXX/XXX-latest.jar"]
```

Next is my start command

```
docker run --rm -d  -p 0.0.0.0:9999:9999 -v /projectFiles/logs/:/opt/XXX/logs/ --name XXX XXX:20190605
```

springboot application.yaml  used log4j

```
logging:
  file: ./logs/log.log
  level:
    xatu.zsl: debug
    org.springfromework.web: info
    org.hibernate: error
```

docker inspect

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/projectFiles/logs",
                "Destination": "/opt/AutoTestPlatform/logs",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Please include your Dockerfile, and docker-compose.yml, if you're using it. Also, avoid posting images of files, use the Stackoverlow code formatting markdown.

Comment: FROM openjdk:8-jdk
LABEL maintainer="XXX"

WORKDIR /opt/XXX
ADD  target/dist/XXX/    /opt/XXX/
ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime && echo ${TZ} > /etc/timezone
EXPOSE 9999

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Denv=PRO","-jar","/opt/AutoTestPlatform/ThemeScreenshot-latest.jar"]

Comment: I meant in the body of the quesiton. I have made an edit to include it, should appear shortly. Please use the same for future questions on the site.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used Stack Overflow for the first time.

Comment: How are logs being written? Can you show your logging configuration for the application?

Comment: For instance, your entrypoint is just writing to stdout by default. Why are you expecting log files in a folder at all?

Comment: I have added the settings for application.yaml. The log is normally generated in the container, but it is not displayed in the folder of the host. I added docker inspect mounts to the question.

Comment: I want the log to be persisted on the host, so I set up to mount the container's log folder to the specified folder.